# rewriting linq-to-sql query with 2 from clauses to a join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have several queries with 2 from clauses that look like this:

```
var TheResult = from a in MyDC.Table1
                from b in MyDC.Table2
                where a.SomeCol == b.SomeOtherCol
                select new MyModel() {....}
```

I'm concerned that this syntax is creating a cartesian join and I want to rewrite it with `join` syntax with only one `from` clause. My question is this: how should I determine which table should I put in the `from` clause?

Thanks.

**Edit: the t-sql generated by the query starts with `SELECT COALESCE((` is that a good/bad thing?**

Comment: Are you concerned that it *might* be doing a cross-product or do you *know* that it is? Otherwise the above should be an inner join.

Comment: I'm indeed concerned it might create a cross-join and induce performance problems.

Comment: You could fire up SQL Server Profiler and watch exactly what SQL it is generating and executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite this into a JOIN pretty easily:

```
var result = from a in MyDC.Table1
             join b in MyDC.Table2 on a.SomeCol equals b.SomeOtherCol
             select new MyModel() { SomeProp = a.SomeCol, SomeProp2 = b.SomeCol }
```

Or if you want a left join:

```
var result = from a in MyDC.Table1
             join b in MyDC.Table2 on a.SomeCol equals b.SomeOtherCol
             into myGroup
             from m in myGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new MyModel() { SomeProp = a.SomeCol, SomeProp2 = m.SomeCol }
```

Comment: In the first sample code you provide, I could also write it as "from a in MyDC.Table2 join b in MyDC.Table1 on b.SomeCol equals a.SomeOtherCol" Would it make any difference? It if it would, how should I choose which order each table goes in?

Comment: Table order doesn't matter for INNER joins. You will only get results where `b.SomeCol` equals `a.SomeOtherCol` and both of those aren't `null`.

Comment: I took a look; can you post the whole query? Not sure what result it would produce because I can't see what the parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

The model you have provided is too much data oriented and don't have a good object oriented feel for understanding how the issue can be solved.

Thinking about object, an example of what you have would be:

```
var TheResult = from u in context.Users
            from c in MyDC.Countries
            where u.CountryId == c.Id
            select new MyModel() { UserName = u.Name, CountryName = c.Name }
```

Having something like that, you can add (and you should!) a relationship between User (mapped to Table1) and Country (mapped to Table2), so you can do:

```
var country = user.Country;
```

This will let you do a more straight forward query, totally supported by Linq-to-sql (and fully enocouraged!):

```
var TheResult = from u in context.Users
                select new MyModel() { UserName = u.Name, CountryName = u.Country.Name }
```

Hope it helps.